# Loop over a string in zsh and Bash

Tags: bash, zsh, quoting, variable

I would like to convert this Bash loop:

```
x="one two three"

for i in ${x}
do
    echo ${i}
done
```

in such a way to work with both Bash and zsh

This solution works:

```
x=( one two three )

for i in ${x[@]}
do
    echo ${i}
done
```

Anyway I am modifying `x` from a string to an array.

Is there a way to loop over `$x` in zsh when it is a string and in a way compatible with Bash?

I know about zsh `setopt shwordsplit` to emulate Bash, but I can't set it *ad hoc* for the loop, because it would not work in Bash.

`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if type emulate >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then emulate ksh; fi
```

In zsh, this activates options that make it more compatible with ksh and bash, including `sh_word_split`. In other shells, `emulate` doesn't exist so this does nothing.

Answer (score 25):

> Is there a way to loop over $x in zsh when it is a string and in a way compatible with Bash?

Yes!. A var expansion is not split (by default) in zsh, but **command expansions are**. Therefore in both Bash and zsh you can use:

```
 x="one two three"

 for i in $( echo "$x" )
 do
    echo "$i"
 done
```

In fact, the code above works the same in all Bourne shell descendants (but not in the original Bourne, change `$(…)` to `` `…` `` to get it working there).

The code above still have some issues with globbing and the use of echo, keep reading.

---

---

In zsh, a var expansion like `$var` is not split (also not glob) by default.
This code has no problems (doesn't expand to all files in the pwd) in zsh:

```
var="one * two"
printf "<%s> " ${var}; echo
```

But also doesn't split var by the value of IFS.

For zsh, splitting on IFS could be done by either using:

```
 1. Call splitting explicitly: `echo ${=var}`.
 2. Set SH_WORD_SPLIT option: `set -y; echo ${var}`.
 3. Using read to split to a list of vars (or an array with `-A`).
```

But none of those options are portable to bash (or any other shell except ksh for `-A`).

Going down to an older syntax that is shared by both shells: `read` might help.
But that can only work for **one character delimiters** (not IFS), and only if the delimiter exists in the input string:

```
 # ksh, zsh and bash(3.0+)
 t1(){  set -f;
        while read -rd "$delimiter" i; do
            echo "|$i|"
        done <<<"$x"
     }
```

Where `$1` is a **one character** delimiter.

That still suffer of the expansion of globbing characters (`*`, `?` and `[`), so a `set -f` is required. And, we can set an array variable `outarr` instead:

```
 # for either zsh or ksh
 t2(){ set -f; IFS="$delimiter" read -d $'\3' -A outarr < <(printf '%s\3' "$x"); }
```

And the same idea for bash:

```
 # bash
 t3(){ local -; set -f; mapfile -td "$1" outarr < <(printf '%s' "$x"); }
```

The effect of `set -f` is restored in the bash function by using `local -`.

The concept could even be extended to a limited shell like dash:

```
 # valid for dash and bash
 t4(){  local -; set -f;
        while read -r i; do
             printf '%s' "$i" | tr "$delimiter"'\n' '\n'"$delimiter"; echo
        done <<-EOT
$(echo "$x" | tr "$delimiter"'\n' '\n'"$delimiter")
EOT
     }
```

No `<<<`, no `<(…)` and no `read -A` or `readarray` used, but it works (for **one character** delimiters) with spaces, newlines, and/or control characters in the input.

But it is a lot easier to simply do:

```
 t9(){ set -f; outarr=(   $(printf '%s' "$x")   ); }
```

Sadly, zsh doesn't understand the `local -`, so the value of `set -f` has to be restored as this:

```
 t99(){ oldset=$(set +o); set -f; outarr=( $( printf '%s' "$x" ) ); eval "$oldset"; }
```

Any of the functions above may be called with:

```
 IFS=$1 delimiter=$1 $2
```

Where the first argument `$` is the delimiter (and IFS) and the second argument is the function to call (t1, t2, … t9, t99). That call sets the value of IFS only for the duration of the function call which gets restored to its original value when the function called exits.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not afraid to use eval (= evil):

```
x="one two three"
eval "x=($x)"
for i in ${x[@]}; do 
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: the "simpler" solution is not simpler at all; at a contrary, it will fork an extra process (subshell) in `bash`. The only advantage is that it will be able to handle `;`, `|`, `(`, etc but **not** `*` in the `x` variable. Your initial solution (using eval) was just better.

Comment: How is the (new) first part of this answer better than [the answer I already posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491459/265604)?

Comment: @mosvy (1)The initial answer (as the second answer) is affected by globbing. That is easy to avoid (correctly) by doing `set -f`. (2) But "the original answer" (with eval) is also affected by a second expansion step which is very difficult to resolve (I would say: impossible to solve). (3) You are missing the point that the `$(echo "$x")` is perfectly portable to **all** bourne like shells. (4) If you want solutions that correctly process any input including spaces, newlines and/or control characters, then: [read my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491459/265604).

Comment: @Isaac Oops, sorry Isaac, I actually realized this different method without reading your answer that has the exact same method. You have to believe me on this one. Anyway, I upvoted your answer and it has now more upvotes than me now, which I think is deserved. Also rollbacked the edit.